# converting curl call to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I've got a problem converting curl request into Python requests call:

here is how curl call looks like: (taken from: http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#creating_new_order_api )

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd" \
-d '{
    "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
    "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
    "merchantPosId": "145227",
    "description": "RTV market",
    "currencyCode": "PLN",
    "totalAmount": "21000",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Wireless Mouse for Laptop",
            "unitPrice": "15000",
            "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "HDMI cable",
            "unitPrice": "6000",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}'
```

and here is what I wrote in requests:

```
import json
import requests
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd',
}

data = {
    "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
    "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
    "merchantPosId": "145227",
    "description": "RTV market",
    "currencyCode": "PLN",
    "totalAmount": "21000",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Wireless Mouse for Laptop",
            "unitPrice": "15000",
            "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
             "name": "HDMI cable",
             "unitPrice": "6000",
             "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}

resp2 = requests.post('https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders', headers=headers, json=data)
print(resp2.json())
```

curl as a response prints out:

```
{"orderId":"V6GRPMNRLR160429GUEST000P01","status":{"statusCode":"SUCCESS"},"redirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/co/summary?sessionId=HtnLqVtBJ5tcOKG2nX03TKwAXOYtXPHe&merchantPosId=145227&timeStamp=1461948331350&showLoginDialog=false&apiToken=9f31fcd1d0d1c5fde8aa57c2b16b5d6bbdfe81543a5f6a12cd39955a487fdaab"}
```

whereas python requests:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.        
  SNIMissingWarning                                                                                                                                                                                                       
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.                                                                           
  InsecurePlatformWarning                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/billing/testapi.py", line 30, in <module>                                                                                                                                              
    print(resp2.json())                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 808, in json                                                                                                                                     
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 488, in loads                                                                                                                                      
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)                                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode                                                                                                                                      
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)                                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 389, in raw_decode                                                                                                                                  
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())                                                                                                                                                                        
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 8 column 1 (char 7)
```

does anyone know why it's not working with requests ? thanks

Comment: Define "not working", does it give an error?

Comment: when I call requests it doesn't print out curl response: it should have been something like "{"orderId":"V6GRPMNRLR160429GUEST000P01","status":{"statusCode":"SUCCESS"},"redirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/co/summary?sessionId=HtnLqVtBJ5tcOKG2nX03TKwAXOYtXPHe&merchantPosId=145227&timeStamp=1461948331350&showLoginDialog=false&apiToken=9f31fcd1d0d1c5fde8aa57c2b16b5d6bbdfe81543a5f6a12cd39955a487fdaab"}" . When I do requests I get "simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 8 column 1 (char 7)  "

Comment: What you get is a stacktrace. Add it to the question.

Comment: Does the error occur on the `resp2 = request.post(...)` line, or the `print(resp2.json())` line?

Comment: the response you are getting is not json. the call returned html.

Comment: So you go a **different** response. Instead of `print(resp.json())` do `print(resp.text)` and perhaps look at the headers and the status code.

Comment: How is the `Authorization` supposed to be formed? Is there perhaps a calculation you need to perform?

Comment: Side note: using the `json` argument automatically sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, so you don't need to do so yourself. The `import json` is also redundant.

Comment: I've just added curl and requests output I get after calling them. I just wanted to convert curl into requests but It didn't work for me at all. I think I should get a python requests response similiar to curl, does it make a sense ?

Comment: It certainly makes sense, and your translation is correct. Clearly the server is responding differently because of some difference. The only differences I can see in the headers produced are the User-Agent and the Accept headers. I'm experimenting now.

Comment: Ah, you get *redirected*; the actual response is a 302.

Comment: Found the reason why; the site redirects as soon as there is a `Accept-Encoding` header present. Which is *very strange behaviour*, probably due to some special case of trying to detect a specific client, or an outright bug.

Comment: Next time instead of writing out the Python by hand, try https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site responds with a *302 status code*, including a Location header:

```
>>> resp = requests.post('https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders', headers=headers, json=data)
>>> resp.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> resp.history[0].headers['location']
'https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/co/summary?sessionId=rrQ97fR2bxQJhUqCDORCbRa0uA4WlxJi&merchantPosId=145227&timeStamp=1461950205252&showLoginDialog=false&apiToken=f3599eca78ad55a16d84608e69f3ac7458b782598b064b337be07e8bd6c2c1d5'
>>> resp.history[0].text
u'{"orderId":"Z9W2H77TVD160429GUEST000P01","status":{"statusCode":"SUCCESS"},"redirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/co/summary?sessionId=rrQ97fR2bxQJhUqCDORCbRa0uA4WlxJi&merchantPosId=145227&timeStamp=1461950205252&showLoginDialog=false&apiToken=f3599eca78ad55a16d84608e69f3ac7458b782598b064b337be07e8bd6c2c1d5"}'
```

You can look at the redirection history (like I did above) by looking at the `response.history` list, which contains preceding requests. `resp.history[0]` was the initial response here. See [*Redirection and History*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) in the documentation.

Note that the data is *right there* on the initial response.

The site does this when you use *any* `Accept-Encoding` header; you get the same result if you add

```
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
```

to the `curl` command, or by adding the same header (with any value) to the [supplied payu.apiari.io console](http://docs.payu21.apiary.io/#reference/api-endpoints/order-api-endpoint/create-a-new-order?console=1) (click *Headers*, then add the `Accept-Encoding` header and add a value for the header).

You should consider this a bug in the site, as specifying that header is a *perfectly normal thing to do*. In fact, the Python `httplib` library (used indirectly by `requests`) sets a *default value* for that header if you omit it yourself, so this is not something `requests` can even switch off. As such, I've reported this to PayU as a bug.

As a work-around, you can use the `response.history[0]` reference, or better yet, tell requests not to follow the redirect in the first place:

```
>>> resp = requests.post('https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders', headers=headers, json=data, allow_redirects=False)
>>> resp.json()
{u'orderId': u'NBWTP5WNKK160429GUEST000P01', u'status': {u'statusCode': u'SUCCESS'}, u'redirectUri': u'https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/co/summary?sessionId=PcvceJHf5En60Dier5gKxCyExiva4qh0&merchantPosId=145227&timeStamp=1461950329704&showLoginDialog=false&apiToken=5962ef901010ca4f8ef6491619217c060f4d53ed0d8e4eadb513d4e0811fc992'}
```

But take care that ignoring the 302 may interfere with the normal status codes, I see that [a 302 may indicate that additional security info is required](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#references_statuses).

Comment: thank you Martijn for pointing it out, that solves my problem.