# Converting cURL call with encode to python request

Tags: python, curl

Now before this gets marked as duplicate and downvoted, I've tried all the other links like (see below) and they don't help.

[converting curl call to python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943604/converting-curl-call-to-python-requests)

[Convert cURL request to Python-Requests request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585800/convert-curl-request-to-python-requests-request)

the cURL call i'm making is (Theres $ interpolation as its in an .sh file)

```
COOKIE_JAR=./program.cookies
LOGIN_URL= 'URL'
USER_ID = 'USERID'
PASSWORD = 'password'
VIEWSTATE = 'long string of text'

$(curl"$LOGIN_URL"-L -b "$COOKIE_JAR" -c "$COOKIE_JAR"
--data-urlencode "__VIEWSTATE=$viewstate" --data-urlencode "userid=$USER_ID" 
--data-urlencode "password=$PASSWORD") || printf >2 "failed to get token:\n%s" 
"$token" && printf "your token is:\n%s\n" "$token"
```

How can i translate this to the python requests form? Any help will be greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: What do you mean with "they don't help"? The server doesn't get the right data or do you get an error?

Comment: As in, its a different form as I have to deal with cookies as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, its okay i got it working! didnt need the cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it working, if anyone needs it:

```
 payload = {
        'userid': USERID,
        'password': PASSWORD,
        '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate # defined earlier
    }
    with requests.Session() as s:
        x = s.get(URL, params=payload,headers=headers)
        token = x.text
```

Didn't need the cookies after all!